# Issue with Scala recursive types (to build a Hlist)

Tags: scala

I'm trying to build a Heterogeneous list recursive type for [a small Scala utility lib](https://github.com/scala-hamsters/hamsters). 
I have issues to concatenate 2 Hlist and keep consistent types.

```
trait HList {
  def ::[U](v: U): HList
}

class HNil extends HList {
  override def ::[T](v: T) = HCons(v, this)
}    

case object HNil extends HNil

case class HCons[T, U <: HList](head: T, tail: U) extends HList {

  def ++[V <: HList, R <: HList](l2: V): HCons[T, R] = {
    def append(l1: HCons[T, _], l2: V): HCons[T, _] = {
      l1.tail match {
        case HNil => HCons(l1.head, l2)
        case h: HCons[T, U] => l1.head :: append(h, l2)
      }
    }
    append(this, l2) match {
      case h: HCons[T,R] => h
    }
  }
}
```

This is working, so at runtime the types are OK :

```
val sum = (2.0 :: "hi" :: HNil) ++ (1 :: HNil)
sum shouldBe 2.0 :: "hi" :: 1 :: HNil
sum shouldBe a[HCons[_, HCons[_, HCons[_, HNil]]]]
```

But the following code is not compiling :

```
val sum = (2.0 :: "hi" :: HNil) ++ (1 :: HNil)
sum.tail.head
```

: `value head is not a member of Nothing`

Do you know how to tell the computer to pick the right type for sum.tail, i.e a HCons[Int, HNil] ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the compiler can't determine the result type `R` from just the argument types. If you look, you don't actually have any code that determines it. So the compiler chooses `Nothing`.

To get around this problem, I believe the smallest possible solution is to use inner types with an `Appender` type class, rather than going straight for the implementation inside `HCons` as you have here.

A full solution written up much better than I would be able to is here: http://jnordenberg.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/hlist-in-scala.html

Comment: Thanks, indeed my current version uses something inspired by this blog :)  Bu I have other issues with it, I think I will open another question about it :)